# UIBarbuttonItemStyle - CLLocation

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios5, uikit

I'm currently designing an app that will leverage the following components:

```
-CoreLocation

-MapKit

-MkMapView
```

One of the requirements of my app is to display the users current location. In the event that the user scrolls away from their currently location, I'd like to provide a means to snap back to their current location on the MKMapView. To give a better visual, think of the default Maps app that comes with iOS.

**Question**

Is there a default UIBarbuttonItemStyle that looks like the locator icon in the bottom toolbar on the Map app?

Comment: Have you not gone through the list of default items in Interface Builder?

Comment: I did, and then I began investigating default icons provided by iOS5. I'll have to consider an alternate solution.

Comment: You may be looking for `MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem` (search for it on SO or Apple docs).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yes, the behaviours exactly what I need. The problem is I can't seem to get the locator icon to appear within in.

Comment: I'm not sure if this makes a difference, but I'm currently designing my UI using storyboards. That being said I've embedded my HomeViewController within a NavigationController and I've been adding a UIToolBar (along with its BarButtonItems) through IB.

Answer (score 2):

Managed to figure it out. Turns out I had to add the following code in my 'viewDidLoad' event:

```
MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem *trackingBarButtonItem = [[MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem alloc] initWithMapView: self.mapView];

self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;

[self setToolBardItems:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: trackingBarButtonItem, nil]];
```

Turns out the default style applied to a MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem includes the locator icon I was looking for originally.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no "default" barButtonItem that contains the locator symbol. You will have to create your own image and add it yourself.

Here are the default items:

[image]